# Roots of cubic polynomial when a coefficient is an infinite list

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, polynomials

I would like to have an expression of the roots of a cubic equation of the type $x^3+ \gamma x^2 + kx = f(k)$ where $\gamma \in [0,1]$, $k$ is an integer and
where $f(k) = \{|k|,|k|+2, |k|+4,...\}$.
I think I'm able to do it using the functions Reduce (with Cubics True) and a finite number of values of $k$ (using Table) but I need the infinite list. Many thanks

Comment: How do you expect to store the infinite list in *Mathematica*?

Comment: How about Function[{k, d, gamma}, 
  Solve[x^3 + gamma*x^2 + k*x == Abs[k] + 2*d, x, 
   Cubics -> True]][a, b, c] ?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I was expecting to have the roots as a recursive formula or as a list depending on two parameters: k, and the parameter indexing the list entry

Comment: @user64494 that might work, I'll try it and let you know thanks

Comment: I experimented a bit with trying to find a recursive solution but without success.